# Term for someone who always changes their aesthetic?

Tags: meaning, terminology

I seem to always change my aesthetic, or at least fit into most aesthetics and adapt to them easily. This mainly affects my fashion and choice of wallpaper customization.

For example, I'd be into a more edgy grunge aesthetic for a month, and suddenly I'm into soft aesthetics the next month. I'm wondering if there's a term for someone who does this specifically or at least does something similar to this. Answers are appreciated!

Comment: What does "up" mean here?

Comment: Are you looking for [dilettante](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilettante)?

Answer (score 1):

This could be called [*aesthetic] dynamism* and the person displaying this characteristic, **dynamic.**

> Characterized by continuous change, activity, or progress: *a dynamic housing market.*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

I would call such a person ***versatile***:

> Able to adapt or be adapted to many different functions or activities; liable to unpredictable variation([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/versatile.html))

E.g.

> He was one of the most ***versatile*** of Roman poets, who wrote love poems,
> elegies, and satirical epigrams with equal success.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/versatile) defines it as

> capable of or adapted for turning easily from one to another of
> various tasks, fields of endeavor, etc.:
>
> - e.g. a versatile writer.